# Cakephp, how using try catch in action of controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I have one model with associative data, with relation hasMany through,
Example-models:

One
   OneTwo
   Two

When I update my object One with containing objects OneTwo, I need to delete old objects OneTwo.

I use saveAssociated for save object One, with atomic = false.

I'm handling the transaction manually, example at fly:

```
$save = false;
$dataSource->begin();
try{        

    $One->OneTwo->deleteAll(conditions);

    $saveAssociated( $one ); //if exception for anythings go catch

    $save = true;
}catch( Exception $e ){
    //print exception in log

}

if($save){
    //commit
}else{
    //rollback
}
```

but the block try catch is ignored for cake, in exception not go at the catch, continue normal.

as I can use a block try catch in cake??

Comment: I am pretty sure CakePHP does not throw errors, so `try-catch` blocks are not useful here. You should look at CakePHP's documentation.

Comment: Well for me would be quite useful to use try catch in this situation, for me is not suitable to launch an exception and stop the execution of my program, i need control the exception manually, i found this:  http://redhead-it.com/blog/2010/02/cakephp-catching-error-in-model-query/ , but i would like use the try at the level action. Very thanks, sorry for my english XD.